# Extraer datos sin usar variables extra

Tags: c++, revisión-de-código, c++11, template

Quiero extraer un dato de una clase; actualmente, utilizo una variable auxiliar para ello.

Funcionar, funciona ... pero me preguntaba si se podría hacer de otra forma, ahorrándome la variable dentro de la función `Envoltura::result( )`:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base {
  void ( *move )( Base *, void * );

  inline Base( void ( *m )( Base *, void * ) ) : move( m ) { }
};

template< typename T > struct Derivada : public Base {
  T value;

  static inline void do_move( Base *b, void *p ) {
    Derivada *d = static_cast< Derivada * >( b );
    new ( p ) T( std::move( d->value ) );
  }

  inline Derivada( ) : Base( do_move ), value( 10 ) { }
};

template< typename T > struct Envoltura {
  Base *base;

  inline T result( ) {
    union {
      T tmp;
      char dummy;
    };

    base->move( base, &tmp );
    return tmp;
  }

  inline Envoltura( ) : base( new Derivada< T >( ) ) { }
};

int main( ) {
  Envoltura< int > e;
  int result = e.result( );

  std::cout << "Resultado: " << result << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

<sub>Compilado con `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic`</sub>

**EDITO**

Es necesario mantener la jerarquía de clases expuesta: una `Base`, una `template< > Derivada` hija de la primera, y una tercera `template< > Envoltura` si herencia de las anteriores. Y **no** puedo usar funciones virtuales.

Comment: Entiendo que los punteros a función no se pueden modificar... verdad?

Comment: Hay 2 requisitos: sin funciones virtuales, y usando exactamente 3 clases: Base, Derivada y Envoltura. Por lo demás, *via libre* :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo, de primeras, procuraría no convertir el dato hasta el final para evitar, en la medida de lo posible, copiar valores. Pudiendo copiar punteros...

```
inline T result( ) {
  void * tmp;

  base->move( base, tmp );
  return static_cast<T>(*tmp);
}
```

Además así te podrías beneficiar del uso de la sintaxis *move* (si está implementada) o de la omisión de copia (*copy elision*).

Aun así sigues teniendo una variable temporal... para eliminarla sería necesario modificar un poco el diseño:

```
struct Base {
  using FuncPtr = void*(*)(Base*);
  FuncPtr move;

  inline Base( FuncPtr m ) : move( m ) { }
};

template< typename T > struct Derivada : public Base {
  T value;

  static inline void* do_move(Base *b) {
    Derivada *d = static_cast< Derivada * >( b );
    return &(d->value);
  }

  inline Derivada( ) : Base( do_move ), value( 10 ) { }
};

template< typename T > struct Envoltura {
  Base *base;

  inline T result( ) {
    return std::move(*static_cast<T*>(base->move(base)));
  }

  inline Envoltura( ) : base( new Derivada<T> ) { }
};
```

Ahora el valor no se extrae mediante un argumento sino vía `return`. La clase `Envoltura` se limita entonces a convertir el valor en el tipo que interese en cada momento.

Comment: ¡ Perfecto ! ¡ Justo lo que estaba buscando !

Comment: Una duda ... `return *static_cast< T * >( base->move( base ) );` devuelve una copia, ¿ cierto ? ¿ No se podría *mover* ?

Comment: @Trauma ¿así te gusta más? :) eso sí, piensa que entonces no podrás hacer dos `return` de la misma `Envoltura`

Comment: ¡¡ Ahora si que si !! :-D